# Problems accessing my computer

Tags: windows-7

I worked for a company that made us buy a laptop from them, everytime I went to log in I had to call and get the login/password from them because it was only used for work. Needless to say I have left that job. Now I cannot log in to the computer. I have tried to login on safe mode with command prompt and it just boots normally. How can I fix this? While I was working for them I had to pay for the laptop now they will not tell me how to unlock it so at the moment I have a $2,300 paperweight... Please help

Comment: Why not wipe it, and reinstall Windows?

Comment: **made us buy a laptop**?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to log in using the local admin account. On the log in screen type administrator and the domain will change to the local computer name. Then type that example: localname\admin or administrator. If there is a local admin password and the account isn't locked use hirens boot cd to change the admin password. It's a long shot but I have done it before. If that works you can continue using the laptop with the local account. It will still be tied to the domain but you at least you can use it.

Comment: If that doesn't work install a fresh windows copy (same version that came with it) and use the activation code on the sticker on the laptop. (Might be easier)

Comment: In my opinion it's better to reinstall windows from scratch after you'll backup all your data - who knows what they changed on your pc too.

Comment: He cant back up the data if he cant log in. However yes it would be optimal to back up your data after logging in and install a fresh copy of windows.

Comment: He can backup using any linux livecd

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to wipe the disk and reinstall Wndows from scratch.